# Is there a way to databind to a list of doubles for editing in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a list of doubles which I need to display.  The user can remove elements, add elements, or change the elements.  Right now I am making text boxes and buttons in a for loop.  Is there a quickier way to do this with databinding?

WPF VS2010 2010 C#

Comment: You do not need to define your UI in the code behind, use XAML...binding the varying properties such as TextBox.Text to the type you want to edit...in this case a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ItemsControl or a control that inherits from it. All you need is a DataTemplate.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDoublesList}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
         <Button Command="{Binding MyButtonCommand}" />
         <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

There is a good overview on MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to what Brady said you probably want to wrap your doubles in a class, doubles are primitive types and hence if you have a collection of them they are not guaranteed to be unique so i'd bind to a `ObservableCollection<DoubleWrapper>` with `DoubleWrapper` only containing one property `Value` of type `double`.